# How to read email from inbox in javascript code

Tags: javascript, email, exchange-server

I have an exchange email account and codecept-js e2e test, which must check if mail was truly sent from a user form and get some data from its body.

I did some research with smtp-client library and that didn't helped - I've met some authorization errors (no plain authorization available, no login auth available) and when I've checked available auth mechanisms - it was GSSAPI,NTLM.

```js
const {SMTPClient} = require('smtp-client');
...
let s = new SMTPClient({
        host: smtpHost,
        port: smtpPort,
    });

    await s.connect();
    I.say('connected');
    await s.greet({hostname: smtpHost}); // runs EHLO command or HELO as a fallback
    I.say('greeted');
    await s.authLogin({username: emailUser, password: pass}); // authenticates a user
    I.say('authorized');
    await s.quit(); // runs QUIT command
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You can't authenticate?

Comment: @IsaacVidrine with that code snippet - yes. Globally - I cant read email inbox.

Comment: in the `smtp-client` examples they use `s.authPlain`... might try that instead

Comment: @IsaacVidrine nope, I've tried both of them - none worked